# Automatically fire bullets instead of depending on key press?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to develope a game using canavas,html5 and javascript. My question is I want to fire bullets automatically after every 300 ms in the code given below.But instead they get fired depending on key press.Please help

My game code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
#canvas{
border:inset 1px black;
}
</style>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



var ballX = 0;
var ballY = 270;
var bulletY=270
var bulletX=50;
draw();
bullet();
function bulletFire()
{
if(bulletY<0)
 {
   bulletY=270;
   bullet();
 }
 else       
 bulletY-=10;
}

function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,300);   
  ctx.fillStyle="black"
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(ballX, ballY,100,30);
  ctx.closePath(); 
  ctx.fill();   
}
function bullet()
{
//ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,300);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(bulletX, bulletY,15,30);
  ctx.closePath();
}

  // Here we just handle command keys
  function keyDownHandler(event) {

  // get which key the user pressed
  var key = event.which;

  // Let keypress handle displayable characters
  if (key > 46) {
    return;
  }

  switch (key) {
    case 37:if(ballX!=0)
        // left key
            { 
        // move the ball 1 left by subtracting 1 from ballX
        ballX -= 4;
        bulletX -=4;
       }


        break;

    case 39:
        // right key
          if(ballX!=300)
        // move the ball 1 right by adding 1 to ballX
        {
        ballX += 4;
        bulletX +=4;
        }  

        break;

    default:
        break;
  }

  // redraw everything
  draw();
  bullet();   
  window.setInterval(bulletFire,300);    
}
//draw();


// Listen for when the user presses a key down
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, true);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have the timer inside your keyDown handler.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows you to define a `keydown` handler as well as a `keyup` handler. You usually use these to toggle variables which state which keys are currently "up" or "down". They only set these variables - nothing else.

Additionally, the game mechanics are usually implemented in an update-function - a function which is executed at regular intervals. In Javascript, you can easily schedule the execution of such a function with the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) function.

During that function, you check which keys are currently "down" and perform the corresponding action. This function should also update the positions of all objects not controlled by the player, check for collisions, and perform the interactions when objects collide.